# BFS (level order traversal) in tree

Tags: c++, tree, breadth-first-search

```
void traverse(Node* root)
{
    queue<Node*> q;
    if (root) 
        q.push(root);
    while (!q.empty())
    {
      const Node * const temp_node = q.front();
        q.pop();
        cout<<temp_node->value<<"\n";

        if (temp_node->left) {
            q.push(temp_node->left);
        }
        if (temp_node->right) {
            q.push(temp_node->right);
        }
    }
}
```

in BFS(level order traversal) why is there a use of const Node*; what is the use of const here, and what would be the problem without const?

Comment: Your question title is inconsistent with your real question.

Answer (score 1):

const is a keyword that indicates to the compiler that you do not intend to write to a variable and only want to read from it. In terms of the logic of an algorithm it should not affect the final result nor the correctness of it. It is usually used for optimization or memory protection. In this particular case I suspect it's to prevent modification of the nodes during the BFS traversal.

Comment: In fact all instances of `Node *` can be replaced with `const Node *`